# Storing the style property's value into a variable, in JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get the background property of my element. This is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#pt {
    background: rgba(192,15,18,1.00);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="pt" onClick="pick()"></div>
<script>
function pick() {
debugger;
var color = document.getElementById("pt").style.background;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this will work, but it doesn't work. It gives an empty string to `color` variable. I think this is not the right way to get the value of background's property. So, kindly help me, how can i get the value of background's property.

Comment: The `element.style` object contains only inline CSS.

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(element);`

Comment: Thank you. I got it. This will make my concept more clear. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 2):

The style property only contains styles assigned in a `style` attribute or set by scripting. Styles set in a `style` element or an external stylesheet won't be found there, at which point you need different techniques for different browsers (standard techniques for everything but IE, as usual).

**For IE**

```
var color= document.getElementById("pt").currentStyle.background;
```

**Other Browsers**

```
var color= getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("pt")).getPropertyValue(background);
```

Comment: I apply it but it work fine in Chrome, but in rest of the browser (firefox, internet explorer , Microsoft edge) it give an empty string. Big Issue for me.

Comment: I've given a solution for IE(internet explorer) an Other browsers separately !

Comment: What you suggest for internet explorer is not working.

Comment: oh yes check it now check the edit!

Comment: Still not working It return me an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getComputedStyle` as a fall back. You can do something like this:

```
var color =
   (document.getElementById("pt").style.background.length > 0) ?
     document.getElementById("pt").style.background.length : 
     getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("pt")).getPropertyValue("background");
```

The line breaks are only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: What does fall back means? I used only this line getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("pt")).getPropertyValue("background");  It works fine in Chrome but not in rest of the browser.

Comment: Fallback means, a backup method whne the main method doesn't work.